# jQuery - Remove CSS Class after 5 Seconds

Tags: jquery, removeclass

I am adding CSS class dynamically for Articles.
If the Article has published recently I am applying CSS class as **article-unread**, but after **5** seconds, this class has to be Changed automatically to **article-read**.
Can somebody please help me out?

### HTML:

```
<section class="news-articles">
    <article class="article-unread">Unread Article</article>
    <article class="article-read">Read Article</article>
</section>
```

### CSS

```
.article-unread {color:red;}
.article-read {color:green;}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h6cpsss7/)

Comment: what effort have you made with your javascript?

Answer (score 9):

you can use `.setTimeout()` along with duration set to 5 sec.

You would also need to use `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` for adding new class and removing old class:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('.article-unread').removeClass('article-unread').addClass('article-read');
},5000);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [**setTimeout**](http://www.sitepoint.com/settimeout-example/):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.article-read').addClass('sss');
},5000);
```